# Coming up with a statistically accurate formula

Tags: mathematical-statistics, econometrics

I've just recently become fascinated by the world of statistics and I have a question. I want to come up with a formula to evaluate quarterbacks in the NFL based on 5 independent variables, which lead to one dependent variable, which is the quarterback's "rating."

What is the best way to do this, so I can ensure it is statistically valid? I'm thinking of using weighted coefficients, but I don't know how to come up with these, except arbitrarily.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome in this fascinating world. Here is a broad picture related to your question :

You could have a look on [general linear model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_model) to begin with and grab the whole idea. There are indeed some weights which are to be estimated to get a good fit. This estimation can be made by a statistical software, like `r` which , broadly speaking, will also tell you how good is your fit.

Depending to the type of variables you are dealing with, and whether or not some required statistical assumptions are met, you can go for a more general approach known under the name of [generali**zed** linear model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model).

Comment: I think rankings have a rival quality to them that the linear model would struggle in accomodating. For example, I would not be surprised if it predicts that two quarterbacks are both number X.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. I have already begun to familiarize myself with "r" so I guess that's where I'll begin. So basically I have to use trial and error, as r can tell me how good the fit is? @DimitriyV.Masterov What do you suggest I do?

Comment: `r` will find the best coefficients for you. Following Dimtriy question, I would wonder how your rating is represented (like a rank or a numeric value). He thought the first, I thought the later.

Comment: @MJ95 I am not aware of an alternative, hence my comment. It is an interesting question.

Comment: @brumar Ah, makes sense. I'm looking to assign a numeric value to each quarterback, preferably on a scale of -100 to 100. Where do I begin in r? I have my independent variables.

Comment: Your last comment interrogates me : Where does this rating comes from ?  Is it from a dataset you have somewhere and you want to see if you can predict it ? Or you want to build this measure ?